# Fragment onResume not getting called after the expandable listview adapter notifyDataSetChanged is called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment consist of expandable listview and when i update my expandable listview Fragment onResume not getting. Can someone please explain me why onResume is not getting called after adapter notifyDataSetChanged called however its still getting called until i dont update my expandable list view.

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onResume in fragment is not getting called because the fragment which you were using might be inside of another fragment. try putting check on the onResume of parent fragment and check if thats getting hit or not.